# JavaScript, creating a simple finance calculator

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to programming, I'm using this as a bit of a learning exercise more than anything. I have made a simple finance calculator.

```
 var origPrice = 1000;
 var term = 12;
 var interest = 3;
 var aprPayable = 0;
 var termType = 0;

 function interestRates(){
 if (interest < 10){
     aprPayable = 0.01;
 }
 else{
     aprPayable = 0.1;   
    }
 }

 interestRates();

 document.calc.apr.value = origPrice * interest * aprPayable;

 document.calc.pay.value = (origPrice + interest) /term/10;

 }

}
```

The problem I have is with the extremely simple algorithm at the bottom of the code, which attempts to give a monthly payment rate. The problem is the algorithm does not work, it does on paper however. Can anyone suggest what I've done wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? Give the erroneous output and the expected output.

Comment: Could you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us of what you've done so far so we can actually debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I played with your code, once I removed the excess right brackets and the variables that didn't exist, it seems to work fine as you can see from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Trasiva/3qxqhkan/). The only real change I made was

```
console.log("APR: " + origPrice * interest * aprPayable);
console.log("Pay: " + (origPrice + interest) / term / 10);
```

which will actually print them to your debug console instead. You can change that to a variable if you prefer like this:

```
var apr = origPrice * interest * aprPayable;
var pay = (origPrice + interest) / term / 10;
```

Comment: It would be good to post the working code here as a snippet, rather than on another site.